# form plugin with mulitple forms | submit returns last form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-forms-plugin

I am writing my own form validation plugin. I am making to work with multiple forms on a page. when the form is submitted it is validated. The problem I am having is that in the plugin I can loo through the elements of the form but in the .submit I can only access the last form of the set sent to j!uery. my html is 2 forms. on has an input with a name of num and the other has one named alpha. they both have their own submit button. below is the main section of the jQuery plugin. for the plugin in am simply sending it form. o.attr is stores the name of the attribute with the validation rules.

```
    var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
    return this.each(function() 
    {
    form=this;
    var o = options;
    //this gets me both inputs on page load
    $('['+o.attr+']', form).each(function()
    {
        var val=$(this).val()
        alert($(this).attr('name'))
    })
    //on submit It will alert the last forms input regardless of what form i submited
    $(this).submit(function()
    {
        var o = options;
        $('['+o.attr+']', form).each(function()
        {
            var val=$(this).val()
            alert($(this).attr('name'))
        })
        return false;
    })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
form=this;
```

You forgot to declare your form `var`, so it's an accidental global variable and not captured in a closure as you expected.

Consequently by the time the `submit` function is called `form` will always hold the last value of `this` regardless of which form was submitted.

(Use a [lint](http://www.jslint.com/) tool on your code, or an ECMAScript Fith Edition Strict Mode-supporting browser, to detect accidental globals.)

Comment: never thought var made a difference and was optional. thank you for the answer and explanation

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you're making this too complicated on yourself. Would something as simple as this work?

```
$forms = $( 'form' );

$forms.submit(
    $( this ).find( '[' + o.attr + ']' ).each( function(){
        var val = this.value;
        alert( this.getAttribute( 'name' ) );
    });
    return false;
);
```

Comment: over complicated how? What your doing wont accomplish what im doing. Im writing a plugin so the user may send it form or #form or even .forms. what you have will select all forms and its no simpler than what I have.

Comment: The script I have will gather all the inputs for the submitted form and the submitted form only.